# Writing logs in console in a .NET Framework 4.6 Console Application

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-4.6

I tried many ways, but I could not manage to write logs in the console of my .NET Framework 4.6 Console Application. I searched on Stackoverflow and found 2 possible solutions, which did not work:

1. Registering in ConfigureDI as

   > services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());

This first possible solution I could not even test as apparently

> ILoggingBuilder does not contain a definition for AddConsole [...]

2. Registering in ConfigureDI as

   > services.AddSingleton< ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
   >   services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));

I'm using ILogger with dependency injection, like this:

```
public class MyApplication
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;
        public MyApplication(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

        }
        public void Run()
        {    
            _logger.LogInformation("Application Started at {dateTime}", DateTime.UtcNow);             
             //...
        }
    }
```

My Program.cs is like this:

```
public static class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            DependencyInjectionConfiguration.ConfigureDI(services);

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var receiver = serviceProvider.GetService<IReceiver>();

            receiver.MyServiceMethod();
        }
    }
```

and my ConfigureDI method is like this:

```
public static class DependencyInjectionConfiguration
    {
        public static void ConfigureDI(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IReceiver, Receiver>();
            services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>();
            services.AddScoped<HelperXml>();
            //services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
            //services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
            //services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
        }
    }
```

Anyone has a clue on what is wrong here? In addition: Writing on a txt file would be nice too...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to target the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) framework if you wish to use ILogger (part of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging).